# what's the wreq's way of creating custom cookies?

Tags: haskell, cookies

I want to make HTTP requests with some known cookie key-value pairs (e.g `k1=v1; k2=v2; ...`) using [wreq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0), but can't find a convenient way of creating them.

Because [Cookie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:Cookie) has many fields, I'd prefer a smart constructor than having to fill all fields on my own.

By browsing documents, I find [generateCookie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:generateCookie) to be the most promosing one (and that's also the only one I've found that returns a `Cookie`): I can create `SetCookie` and all I need are just key value pairs. But we don't have a [Request](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:Request) to feed it as the second argument. Using http-client alone, one can do [parseUrl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:parseUrl) to create one. But in wreq I feel the author want to hide Request from user and I can't find a function that gives us direct access to it.

So my question is: are there better ways to create cookies in wreq than using `Cookie` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably fork the `generateCookie` implementation, as it looks like the `Request` argument is used only to validate the fields.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.26.2/docs/src/Network-HTTP-Client-Cookies.html#generateCookie, except for default cookie path, as `SetCookie` has `Maybe` path.